# Obter o valor dos atributos customizados no aspnet-identity .NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou usando o **Identity** com **aspnet core 2.0**
e precisei adicionar o atributo *nuCPF* na tabela *ApplicationUser*. No controller estou obtendo os dados do usuário da seguinte forma:

[Controller: **ClienteController**]

```
public ClienteController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int paginaAtual = 1, string filtro = "")
{
    var NomeUsuarioLogado = User.Identity.Name;
    var idUsuarioLogado = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);

    xxxxx.... etc
}
```

A classe **ApplicationUser** está assim:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public string nuCPF { get; set; }
}
```

#### Dúvida 1:

Como eu poderia pegar o valor do campo *nuCPF*?

#### Dúvida 2:

Quando eu uso o *'_userManager.GetUserId(user)'*, é feito um select no banco para obter o id do usuário?

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar todas informações do usuário você deve usar:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Depois só usar `user.NuCPF`

E sim, ele vai no banco pegar as informações.

OBS: troque o nome de `nuCPF` para `NuCPF`. Por convenção os nomes de propriedades começam com letras maiúsculas.

Comment: Fabri, me parece que não existe o método "GetUser" no userManager.
veja como está para mim: https://prnt.sc/irn5jh
É dessa forma mesmo?

Comment: GetUserAsync, use esse

Comment: Não encontra a propriedade nuCPF ao utilizar o "user.NuCPF"

aparece o seguinte erro:
_não contém uma definição para "nuCPF" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "nuCPF" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "Task<ApplicationUser>"_

Comment: Manda o código atual para ver como esta

Comment: 'public ClienteController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var teste = user.nuCPF;
        }'

o ApplicationUser está do jeito da pergunta no post principal.